# I fail to login with requests POST while I lready tried lots of parameter combinations

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

The HTML below describes part of my device's login page:

[image]

the url to get to this screen is http:///login.asp. According to the Network sniffer of chrome (also verified this with wireshark) the POST action during manual login is to `/goform/formLogin`
The user-name and the password field names are **Account_Username** and **Account_Password** correspondingly

I am trying with the following lines to perform a login and it looks like I fail. The only way that I can verify a success is by watching the content of a GET request to a the device url which is not the login page.

```
import requests

url = 'http://10.0.6.66/goform/formLogin'
data = {'Account_Username': 'admin', 'Account_Password': 'admin'}

with requests.Session() as s:
   r = s.post(url, data)
   r_1 = s.get('http://10.0.6.66')
   print(r_1.content)
```

I have also tried to use headers with a relevant content and that didn't do the job `headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:68.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/68.0'}`

What am I doing wrong ? How can I manage to login to my device with requests.post ?

Comment: what is the value of `Content-Type` header for post request?

Comment: What do you mean by that ? I am not familiar with this ?

Comment: I can see this field through the wireshark capture. Do I need to use it in my script ?

Comment: Can you print out the status_code of the response you are getting after your POST call? You should add print('Status_Code: {}'.format(r.status_code) after the POST call.

Comment: I get a 200, but the following get request  results with the content as if I didn't login

Comment: What is the value of that header?

Comment: @Stack ```application/x-www-form-urlencoded``` but this capture was taken from a manual login

Comment: @MosheS. if it's an .asp website then there is a chance that there is some additional post parameters as well "__VIEWSTATE","__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR","__EVENTVALIDATION"

Comment: @ahmed.soli How can I tell if I am missing some POST parameters ?

Comment: @MosheS. provide the url and I can tell you for sure

Comment: I cannot give a url as this is an internal IP in my LAB. Can you please direct me with a few steps that I can try by myself ?

Comment: I got it. I have managed to monitor my Login actions via the device CLI. So I can tell for sure that I do perform Login actions. Now my problem is to see that by using only requests or BeautifulSoup. How can I tell that I failed or succeeded to Login. What I found out is that there is an Http response from the device side that looks like ```Location: http://10.0.6.66/auth.asp#aa=poiuytrewq&auth=admin&bb=mnbvcxz``` when I successfully logged in or ```Location: http://10.0.1.104/auth.asp#aa=poiuytrewq&auth=none&bb=mnbvcxz``` when I failed. Is there a way to monitor this response ?

Comment: The response that indicated above was seen only by using a sniffer